# Removing 'on behalf of' when sending mail using MailGun

Tags: email, go, mailgun, dkim

I'm trying to figure out how to send mails using the MailGun Golang API without having it sent 'on behalf of'.

This is how the From address currently looks (where foo.com is the sender's email domain and bar.com is my domain):

```
john=foo.com@mail.bar.com on behalf of John Smith <john@foo.com>
```

What do I need to do so that it looks like this instead:

```
John Smith <john@foo.com>
```

I've set up SPF and DKIM according to the MailGun instructions and everything passes as being correct.  I've also used `SetDKIM(true)` when I'm sending out the mail.  Is there some setting I'm missing or additional validation I need to do?

Comment: Please try to send email to gmail and post the header of received email in above question

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to set the `sender` property in the email header to the from address as well most likely.

I had this same problem using NodeMailer for a node.js project. Gmail and Thunderbird would show the from address fine but Outlook would show the from address as

```
emailname=example.com@mail.example.com on behalf of emailname@example.com
```

When I looked into the full email message header I saw that the `sender:` in the header was `emailname=example.com@mail.example.com` and the `from:` was `emailname@example.com`

we looked into the spf and dkim records at first thinking it was an issue there but they were fine and in the email header it even said spf and dkim both were passing so then i noticed the sender header was different than the from and Outlook pays attention to that where gmail and thunderbird don't care as much.

Try setting the `sender` header to the `from` value.

Here is a sample of part of one of the wrong email headers edited to match example above

```
Received-SPF: pass (google.com....
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@mail.example.com;
       spf=pass (google.com.....
Sender: emailname=example.com@mail.example.com
From: Persons Name <emailname@example.com>
```

make `Sender` equal to `Sender: Persons Name <emailname@example.com>`

Comment: Thanks. This fixed my issue with Mailgun.

Answer (score 25):

To add to Dhodgin's answer:
The `on behalf of` message comes up if you're using a subdomain in MailGun such as `mail.bar.com` and the from email address is using a different domain such as `john@foo.com`
To fix this issue add a custom MIME header "sender" and set it to be the same as the from email address.
To add a custom header using the  [MailGun api](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-sending.html#sending) make sure to add a `h:` prefix such as:

```
request.AddParameter("h:sender", "John Smith <john@foo.com> ");
```

Comment: This works, but note the header should be "sender" and not "h:sender". When using the MailGun library, AddParameter adds the h: for you.

Comment: This save my life! thanks!! btw I had to include the h:, i tried without it but nothing change until i used the h: to indicate the use of a header value

Comment: I had the same experience as @Ray.

Comment: If any Pythonistas are using the requests library, you can add the "h:sender" like this: ```response = requests.post(url, auth, data={"h:sender": "Name <name@email.com>", ...})```

Comment: I use the API and HAD to add h: (only with sender, it don't work)

Answer (score 18):

### Have you added an mg sub domain?

If you have added a sub-domain such as @mg.domain.com then **make sure you send your emails from name@mg.domain.com**

I had the same problem, as I didn't realize that I wanted to have the sender address *name@domain.com* but I had added - as recommended - a subdomain to mailgun: *mg.domain.com*.

So when I tried to send an email from *name@domain.com* I got "on behalf of" / "sent by" but as soon as I've used the subdomain **name@mg.domain.com** - the "on behalf" message is gone... stupid me...

Comment: Hmm, in Mailgun's setup they say "We recommend using a subdomain with Mailgun, like “mg.mydomain.com”. Using a subdomain you will still be able to send emails from your root domain e.g. “you@mydomain.com”". If that's true, I wonder what the process would be?

Comment: Yeah. Mailgun should not say `Using a subdomain you will still be able to send emails from your root domain` and/or should mention the issues with that setup, which they describe on their own documentation: https://help.mailgun.com/hc/en-us/articles/360012491394-Why-do-I-see-On-Behalf-Of-in-my-email-

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to send from a different domain than the one you setup SPF/DKIM on?

You can only send white-labelled emails from the domain you're authorized with Mailgun.

Comment: No, I'm sending from the domain that I authorized. In other words the mail.bar.com from above is the one that I've specified in Mailgun.

Comment: I think that's the problem!

You need to have setup foo.com in mailgun since you are sending "from" john@foo.com (and not mail.bar.com).

Answer (score 0):

For those using **SMTP** in mailgun **subdomain**. Set the "From" and "Sender" parameter. eg

```
message["From"] = 'John Smith <john@foo.com>'
message["Sender"] = 'john@foo.com'
```