# How to change the sender address in mail in laravel with mail gun

Tags: laravel, email, mailgun

I am sending the email using below code

```
Mail::send('emails.sample',[],function($message) use($attachment,$filename)
        {
            $message->subject('PDF is generated !');
            $message->from('test@example.com', 'Example');
            $message->to('user@gmail.com');
            $message->attachData($attachment,$filename,array('mime'=>'application/pdf','Content-Disposition'=>'attachment'));
        });
```

but after receiving the email, sender email address is coming like this

> test=example.com@mailgun.org on behalf of Example test@example.com

but it should be like either `email address` or `name`

> test@example.com

How do I fix this? any suggestions, please!

Comment: whats is your from email address in config/mail.php

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd: this is what I have in mail.php `'from' => [
        'address' => 'hello@example.com',
        'name' => 'Example',
    ],`

Comment: Please follow this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28401673/removing-on-behalf-of-when-sending-mail-using-mailgun)

Comment: I have set the in `mail.php` and I have run `php artisan confg:cache` but still the issue persists. and my every email will be having different `from` email address.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @Nolesh : I did not get the solution yet :(

Comment: This solution is deprecated with L5.5 ...using Mailable

Answer (score 5):

For anyone still reading this - it's because you need to set the "sender" address. Gmail doesn't seem to care, but Outlook does.

```
$message->sender(config('mail.from.address'));
```

Comment: which file please?

Comment: @shireefkhatab Email Controller.

Answer (score 4):

you can add these in `.env`:

```
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=from@domain.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=From Name Surname
```

in alternative, if you let it blank, you can still change them in `config/mail.php`, here replace with yours:

```
'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'info@idesk.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'IDesk'),
],
```

as you can see `config/mail.php` at first try to read it from `.env` sto `.env` should be used

Answer (score 0):

Gmail automatically rewrites the "from" header of any messages sent through its SMTP server to the default "Send mail as" email address assigned in the Gmail or Google Apps account used to authenticate (in this case, your personal account).

This SMTP service is intended for personal use only, so its not very flexible. We can change this address by modifying the default account in the Gmail settings, but this still won't enable us to configure the "from" address through the application.

In development, this behavior may not matter, but for production environments, we'd need to use a mail provider that respects the headers sent from the application. Gmail also limits the rate of emails sent through its SMTP server in this way, which prevents us from using the service for most applications in production that send any significant amount of email.

Answer (score -1):

In config/mail.php

set from property as:

```
'from' => ['address' => 'test@example.com', 'name' => 'Anything you Want']
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you using sandbox? Because I am also using the mailgun with sandbox and I am not facing this issue

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=postmaster@sandbox3940xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mailgun.org
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=sandboxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxfaf6.mailgun.org
MAILGUN_SECRET=key-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: The above code is from .env and you have to use this info in config/mail.php

Comment: even I have setup the same way, but I don't know why it's not working for me?

Comment: Share your `config/mail.php`

Comment: `return [
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
    'from' => [
        'address' => 'test@example.com',
        'name' => 'Example',
    ],
    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
];`

Comment: Check `config/services.php` here is the code from my `services.php`  `'mailgun' => [
        'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
        'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
    ],`

Comment: Yes, I have the same setup in my `services.php`. I did not change anything in `services.php`.

Comment: Check what I am getting in mail https://nimbus.everhelper.me/client/notes/share/1039913/0o2m4tvunf0r7lhl4qn5

Comment: Yeah, I got you but I am not getting that way whatever I change it's not affecting? i don't understand

Comment: Can you try to send to any outlook email and please let me know how you are getting?

Comment: If you provided all information in .env then you will receive mail like I am receiving and check mailgun portal whether your domain is active or not. I already provided all configuration details which was required to configure mailgun in laravel

Comment: Actually I am not having any outlook email for testing

Comment: Oh okay. if you can try with outlook email, you will also get the same what I am getting.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to set up some DNS records, so your mail provider can verify that mailgun is allowed to send email on behalf of your domain.

http://mailgun-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faqs.html#email-clients-say-sent-via-mailgun-us-with-messages-i-send-how-do-i-get-rid-of-this